# PHP texto que é alterado no campo <textarea> ao sair do modal, o texto não retorna ao original, porque?

Tags: php, bootstrap-3

Boa Tarde

Estou usando o **Varying modal content based on trigger button** do Bootstrap para para criar uma janela de editar produtos.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

eu tenho um campo de `textarea` que não está aparecendo as informações, 
o campo `input` funciona corretamente, só o campo `textarea` não carrega a informação, então fiz

```
 <textarea> <?php echo $informacao; ?>
```

funcionou mas se o usuário abre o modal e altera alguma coisa do **textarea** ao sair e voltar a mudança ainda continua lá.

Como posso resolver esse problemas, quando sair do modal qualquer alteração que ele tenha sido realizada, vota tudo para o que foi carregado do banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Então, isso acontece pq o modal é gerado na sua página enquanto a página é carregada e não quando o método `.show()` é chamado no javascript. Para retornar o valor original do banco de dados você deve alterar o valor do textarea quando o método `.show()` for chamado. Tente algo assim:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('id_do_textarea');
textarea.value = <?php echo $informacao; ?>;
```

Comment: Agora todos os campos ficam brancos